# Java variable number of generics

Tags: java, class, generics

I need a way to implement a class that can take in a variable number of generic parameters. Basically, I need a way to combine the following classes:

```
class IncidentReporter1<A> {
    public void reportIncident(A a) {
    }
}
class IncidentReporter2<A, B> {
    public void reportIncident(A a, B b) {
    }
}
class IncidentReporter3<A, B, C> {
    public void reportIncident(A a, B b, C c) {
    }
}
class IncidentReporter4<A, B, C, D> {
    public void reportIncident(A a, B b, C c, D d) {
    }
}
```

into just one `IncidentReporter` class. I know I can take in a `Class[]` at runtime and use that, but I was wondering if there was a better native way to do this in java.

Comment: If you want to combine all 4 in one, then you need to have that 4-arg method, then you need all 4 type parameters; why not just add all 4 methods to a class with 4 type parameters?

Comment: There's a [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) bouquet to this question

Comment: I may need like 20 arguments in the future. I was planning on just using an Object[] to transmit the data without any generics, but I figured I might as well try with generics to make casting, etc. easier

Comment: Actually this is seems much more like a tuples question.

Comment: Can't be done. What you've got is as good as it gets. That's why Java 8, for instance, included a `Function<T,R>` and `BiFunction<T,U,R>` (instead of just a `Function<T..., R>` or whatever).

Comment: Have you though about replacing all generic arguments one mojo with nullable values? Less complicated code, the better.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/whats-wrong-java-8-part-v

Comment: Okay, thank you, guys. I will stick to using an Object[] to transmit the data without using generics bc it is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just write it like this :

```
public class IncidentReporter {

public void reportIncident(Class<?>... differentClasses) {

}

}
```

Much cleaner i think.

Comment: I did that same thing but used an object[] because I'm transmitting data not just the class types. Thanks!